# Getting Values From Firebase Into A ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have need to populate a list view from the "attendance" node:

[image]

Each list item should show the sport, the date, and the time. Here is what I'm doing to get the values:

```
        final DatabaseReference attendanceRef = database.getReference()
            .child(Constants.MEMBERS_NODE).child(userID).child("attendance").child(today);

    attendanceRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String sport = snapshot.getKey();
                String date = (String) snapshot.child("date").getValue();
                String timeStamp = (String) snapshot.child("timestamp").getValue();

            }
        }
```

notice that I can't just get the value of the snapshot since I need to get the key, which is the sport name. I'm not sure how to approach it. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Create a hashmap to map the values.

```
HashMap<String,String> sportsMap = snapshot.getValue();
String date = sportsMap.get("date");
```

Comment: I tried that, but not sure how would I create a list adapter with that hash map.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the list item to show the sport name with time and date it was attended. The answer wasn't complicated, but it needed little deep understanding.

I should create a model class to get the date and timestamp:

```
public class MemberAttendance {

private String sport;
private long timestamp;

public MemberAttendance() {

}

public MemberAttendance(String sport, long timestamp) {
    this.sport = sport;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getSport() {
    return sport;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setSport(String sport) {
    this.sport = sport;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

Then create a reference like before:

```
final DatabaseReference attendanceRef = database.getReference()
            .child(Constants.MEMBERS_NODE).child(userID).child("attendance").child(today);
```

Then initialize the adapter like so:

```
        attendanceAdapter = new MemberAttendanceAdapter(getActivity(), MemberAttendance.class,
            R.layout.list_item_attendance, attendanceRef);

    attendanceListView.setAdapter(attendanceAdapter);
```

The real trick was in the adapter when I needed to let sport equals the reference key, which is the sport name:

```
public class MemberAttendanceAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<MemberAttendance> {

public MemberAttendanceAdapter(Activity activity, Class<MemberAttendance> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query ref) {
    super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
}

@Override
protected void populateView(View view, MemberAttendance memberAttendance, int i) {

    String sport = getRef(i).getKey();

    // Create views and assign values
    TextView sportTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sportTxtView);
    sportTxtView.setText(sport);

    // This time stamp can return date and time, so there is no need to create a date getter
    Date timestamp = new Date(memberAttendance.getTimestamp());

    TextView dayTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dayTxtView);
    dayTxtView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(timestamp));

    // Show the time
    TextView dateTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTxtView);
    dateTxtView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(timestamp));

}
```

}